# Select All Events with Event->Schedule->Date between start and end dates in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, associations, cakephp-1.3

Trying to figure out how to build a query in CakePHP where I can select all Events that are between X and Y dates (user-entered dates).

The problem lies in that the `Event` doesn't have the dates in it's table.

```
Event hasMany Schedule
Schedule belongsTo Event

Schedule hasMany Date
Date belongsTo Schedule
```

- `Events table`:  details of the event - name, location, description...etc
- `Schedules table`: start and end date with repeat options
- `Dates table`:  the actual dates of the event created from the data in `Schedules`

So - I actually need to select any Events that have at least one Date entry between the X and Y dates.

I also need to be able to display the dates with the event data.

---

**Edit (REVISED):**

I've tried this, but it appears to be retrieving the events regardless of the Date, but only retrieving the Date info if the date falls within the range:

```
$this->Event->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$events = $this->Event->find('all', array(
    'limit'=>5,
    'order'=>'Event.created DESC',
    'contain' => array(
    'Schedule' => array(
        'fields'=>array(),
        'Date' => array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                'start >=' => $start_date,
                'start <=' => $end_date,
                )
            )
        )
    ),
));
```

*Just to clarify - Date.start and Date.end are always the same Date - they just also include a time (both datetime fields) - hence why I'm checking "start" against both.

---

I've tried using containable, I've tried unbind/bindModel..etc - I must be doing something wrong or off-track.

Something to keep in mind - once I figure out how to get the Events based on the Date, I also need to add on other conditions like Event Types and more - not sure if this would affect the answer(s) or not.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's what I'm using that seems to work - also seems very ugly - any thoughts?:

```
function getEvents($opts = null) {
    //$opts = limit, start(date), end(date), types, subtypes, subsubtypes, cities

    $qOpts['conditions'] = array();

    //dates
    $qOpts['start'] = date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
    if(isset($opts['start'])) $qOpts['start'] = $opts['start'];

    $qOpts['end'] = date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';
    if(isset($opts['end'])) $qOpts['end'] = $opts['end'];

    //limit
    $qOpts['limit'] = 10;
    if(isset($opts['limit'])) $qOpts['limit'] = $opts['limit'];

    //fields
    //$qOpts['fields'] = array('Event.id', 'Event.name', 'Event.slug', 'City.name', 'Date.start');  
    // if(isset($opts['fields'])) $qOpts['fields'] = $opts['fields'];


    //date conditions
    array_push($qOpts['conditions'], array(
        "Date.start >=" => $qOpts['start'],
        "Date.start <=" => $qOpts['end'],
    ));

    //cities conditions
    if(isset($opts['cities'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['cities'])) {
            $cityConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['cities'] as $city_id) {
                array_push($cityConditions['OR'], array('OR'=>array('Venue.city_id'=>$city_id, 'Restaurant.city_id'=>$city_id)));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $cityConditions);
        }
    }

    //event types conditions
    //$opts['event_types'] = array('1');
    if(isset($opts['event_types'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['event_types'])) {
            $eventTypeConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['event_types'] as $event_type_id) {
                array_push($eventTypeConditions['OR'], array('EventTypesEvents.event_type_id' => $event_type_id));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $eventTypeConditions);
        }
    }

    //event sub types conditions
    if(isset($opts['event_sub_types'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['event_sub_types'])) {
            $eventSubTypeConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['event_sub_types'] as $event_sub_type_id) {
                array_push($eventSubTypeConditions['OR'], array('EventSubTypesEvents.event_sub_type_id' => $event_sub_type_id));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $eventSubTypeConditions);
        }
    }

    //event sub sub types conditions
    if(isset($opts['event_sub_sub_types'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['event_sub_sub_types'])) {
            $eventSubSubTypeConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['event_sub_sub_types'] as $event_sub_sub_type_id) {
                array_push($eventSubSubTypeConditions['OR'], array('EventSubSubTypesEvents.event_sub_sub_type_id' => $event_sub_sub_type_id));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $eventSubSubTypeConditions);
        }
    }


    $this->recursive = 2;

    $data = $this->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
            'Restaurant' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'slug', 'address', 'GPS_Lon', 'GPS_Lat', 'city_id'),
                'City' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'url_name'),
                ),
            ),
            'Venue' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'slug', 'address', 'GPS_Lon', 'GPS_Lat', 'city_id'),
                'City' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'url_name')
                )
            ),
            'Schedule' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'name'),
                'Date' => array(
                    'fields' => array('start', 'end'),
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Date.start >=' => $qOpts['start'],
                        'Date.start <=' => $qOpts['end'],
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'EventType' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'slug'),
            ),
            'EventSubType' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'slug'),
            ),
            'EventSubSubType' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'slug'),
            ),
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => $this->Schedule->table,
                'alias' => 'Schedule',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Schedule.event_id = Event.id',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'table' => $this->Schedule->Date->table,
                'alias' => 'Date',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Date.schedule_id = Schedule.id',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'table' => $this->EventTypesEvent->table,
                'alias' => 'EventTypesEvents',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'EventTypesEvents.event_id = Event.id',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'table' => $this->EventSubTypesEvent->table,
                //'table' => 'event_sub_types_events',
                'alias' => 'EventSubTypesEvents',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'EventSubTypesEvents.event_id = Event.id',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'table' => $this->EventSubSubTypesEvent->table,
                'alias' => 'EventSubSubTypesEvents',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'EventSubSubTypesEvents.event_id = Event.id',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'conditions' => $qOpts['conditions'],
        'limit' => $qOpts['limit'],
        'group' => 'Event.id'
    ));
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Dave, I'm looking at your updates.There certainly is some way to avoid using Containable AND manual joins, and still get the results you want. I'll look into it and then get back to you. But I'm a little confused with all your OR conditions, and I'm not sure of what data you're trying to get from the DB.

Comment: Also: what's the relationship between Restaurants, Venues and Events?

Comment: @bfavaretto - ty for ANY help - I'm going crazy w/ this.  The "OR"s allow for user to select a list events types they want to narrow the results to.  Ie - I want to only see "sports", "movies", and "outdoor" - so I'm using the "OR to say that the `eventType` has to be one of those types.  Same with `subTypes` and `subSubTypes`...etc.

`Event belongsTo Venue`
`Event belongsTo Restaurant`

(basically, those are both locations the event could be held at - just in separate tables)

Comment: Okay @Dave, I've run some tests and now I understand what is going on. Now I'll be editing my original answer for the details.

Comment: @bfavaretto - I honestly can't wait to see what you've come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT to the rescue!!!  Long story short - I needed to return Events with their many Dates (with being able to query against different HABTM tables) - but when I tried, I'd either get way too many events (one for each date...etc) or I'd use GROUP BY, and not get all the dates.  The answer... still use GROUP BY, but combine the Dates into a single field using GROUP_CONCAT:

```
$qOpts['fields'] = array(
        ...
        'GROUP_CONCAT(Date.start, "|", Date.end ORDER BY Date.start ASC SEPARATOR "||") AS EventDates'
    );
```

I'm posting a lot of code - feel free to browser if you got stuck like I did.

**Things I learned:**

- It's NOT recommended to use contain AND join - pick one and stick with it - this was the bane of my existence for a bit - I'd get something to work, but then not w/ pagination..etc etc.
- If you need to query based on HABTM data, pick join, not contain
- My Joins were working just fine, but I would get the same event 10 times over (1 for each date that existed)
- But when I tried to GROUP BY, it combined them, so I only got 1 date, when I really needed all the dates
- GROUP_CONCAT is amazing (had never heard of it before)

Hope this helps someone.  Feel free to point out any issues w/ my code - I always like to improve.  But for now, I'm dancing in circles because it WORKS!!!  Now that it works, I'm going to go back in and try to clean up those ORs like @bfavaretto mentioned.

```
    //returns events based on category, subcategory, and start/end datetimes
function getEvents($opts = null) {
    //$opts = limit, start(date), end(date), types, subtypes, subsubtypes, cities, paginate(0,1), venues, excludes(event ids)

    $qOpts['conditions'] = array();

    //order
    $qOpts['order'] = 'Date.start ASC';
    if(isset($opts['order'])) $qOpts['order'] = $opts['order'];

    //dates
    $qOpts['start'] = date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
    if(isset($opts['start'])) $qOpts['start'] = $opts['start'];

    //limit
    $qOpts['limit'] = 10;
    if(isset($opts['limit'])) $qOpts['limit'] = $opts['limit'];

    //event excludes (example: when you want "other events at this venue", you need to exclude current event)
    if(isset($opts['excludes'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['excludes'])) {
            foreach($opts['excludes'] as $exclude_id) {
                array_push($qOpts['conditions'], array('Event.id <>' => $exclude_id));
            }
        }
    }

    //approval status conditions
    if(!isset($opts['approval_statuses'])) $opts['approval_statuses'] = array('1'); //default 1 = approved
    if(isset($opts['approval_statuses'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['approval_statuses'])) {
            $approvalStatusesConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['approval_statuses'] as $status) {
                array_push($approvalStatusesConditions['OR'], array('Event.approval_status_id' => $status));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $approvalStatusesConditions);
        }
    }

    //date conditions
    $date_conditions = array();
    array_push($qOpts['conditions'], array('Date.start >=' => $qOpts['start']));
    array_push($date_conditions, array('Date.start >=' => $qOpts['start']));

    if(isset($opts['end'])) {
        array_push($qOpts['conditions'], array('Date.start <=' => $opts['end']));
        array_push($date_conditions, array('Date.start <=' => $opts['end']));
    }


    //venues conditions
    if(isset($opts['venues'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['venues'])) {
            $venueConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['venues'] as $venue_id) {
                array_push($venueConditions['OR'], array('OR'=>array('Venue.id'=>$venue_id)));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $venueConditions);
        }
    }

    //cities conditions
    if(isset($opts['cities'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['cities'])) {
            $cityConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['cities'] as $city_id) {
                array_push($cityConditions['OR'], array('OR'=>array('Venue.city_id'=>$city_id, 'Restaurant.city_id'=>$city_id)));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $cityConditions);
        }
    }

    //event types conditions
    if(isset($opts['event_types'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['event_types'])) {
            $eventTypeConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['event_types'] as $event_type_id) {
                array_push($eventTypeConditions['OR'], array('EventTypesEvents.event_type_id' => $event_type_id));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $eventTypeConditions);
        }
    }

    //event sub types conditions
    if(isset($opts['event_sub_types'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['event_sub_types'])) {
            $eventSubTypeConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['event_sub_types'] as $event_sub_type_id) {
                array_push($eventSubTypeConditions['OR'], array('EventSubTypesEvents.event_sub_type_id' => $event_sub_type_id));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $eventSubTypeConditions);
        }
    }

    //event sub sub types conditions
    if(isset($opts['event_sub_sub_types'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['event_sub_sub_types'])) {
            $eventSubSubTypeConditions['OR'] = array();
            foreach($opts['event_sub_sub_types'] as $event_sub_sub_type_id) {
                array_push($eventSubSubTypeConditions['OR'], array('EventSubSubTypesEvents.event_sub_sub_type_id' => $event_sub_sub_type_id));
            }
            array_push($qOpts['conditions'], $eventSubSubTypeConditions);
        }
    }


    //joins
    $qOpts['joins'] = array();

    //Restaurants join
    array_push($qOpts['joins'], array(
            'table' => $this->Restaurant->table,
            'alias' => 'Restaurant',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Restaurant.id = Event.restaurant_id',
            ),
        )
    );

    //Venues join
    array_push($qOpts['joins'], array(
            'table' => $this->Venue->table,
            'alias' => 'Venue',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Venue.id = Event.venue_id',
            ),
        )
    );

    //Schedules join
    array_push($qOpts['joins'], array(
            'table' => $this->Schedule->table,
            'alias' => 'Schedule',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Schedule.event_id = Event.id',
            ),
        )
    );

    //Dates join
    array_push($qOpts['joins'], array(
        'table' => $this->Schedule->Date->table,
        'alias' => 'Date',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array(
            'Date.schedule_id = Schedule.id',
            //$date_conditions
        ),
    ));

    //Uploads join
    array_push($qOpts['joins'], array(
            'table' => $this->Upload->table,
            'alias' => 'Upload',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Upload.event_id = Event.id',
            ),
        )
    );

    //Event types join
    if(isset($opts['event_types'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['event_types'])) {
            array_push($qOpts['joins'], array(
                'table' => $this->EventTypesEvent->table,
                'alias' => 'EventTypesEvents',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'EventTypesEvents.event_id = Event.id',
                ),
            ));
        }
    }
    if(isset($opts['event_sub_types'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['event_sub_types'])) {
            array_push($qOpts['joins'], array(
                'table' => $this->EventSubTypesEvent->table,
                'alias' => 'EventSubTypesEvents',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'EventSubTypesEvents.event_id = Event.id',
                ),
            ));
        }
    }
    if(isset($opts['event_sub_sub_types'])) {
        if(is_array($opts['event_sub_sub_types'])) {
            array_push($qOpts['joins'], array(
                'table' => $this->EventSubSubTypesEvent->table,
                'alias' => 'EventSubSubTypesEvents',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'EventSubSubTypesEvents.event_id = Event.id',
                ),
            ));
        }
    }

    $qOpts['fields'] = array(
        'Event.*',
        'Venue.id', 'Venue.slug', 'Venue.name', 'Venue.GPS_Lon', 'Venue.GPS_Lat',
        'Restaurant.id', 'Restaurant.slug', 'Restaurant.name', 'Restaurant.GPS_Lat', 'Restaurant.GPS_Lon',
        'GROUP_CONCAT(Date.start, "|", Date.end ORDER BY Date.start ASC SEPARATOR "||") AS EventDates'
    );

    //group by
    $qOpts['group'] = 'Event.id';

    //you need to set the recursion to -1 for this type of join-search
    $this->recursive = -1;


    $paginate = false;
    if(isset($opts['paginate'])) {
        if($opts['paginate']) {
            $paginate = true;
        }
    }

    //either return the options just created (paginate)
    if($paginate) {
        return $qOpts;

    //or return the events data
    } else {
        $data = $this->find('all', $qOpts);
        return $data;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this kind of situation, I tend not to use Cake's associations, or Containable, and craft the joins myself:

```
$events = $this->Event->find('all', array(
    'joins'=>array(
        array(
            'table' => $this->Schedule->table, 
            'alias' => 'Schedule', 
            'type' => 'INNER', 
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array(
                'Schedule.event_id = Event.id',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'table' => $this->Date->table, 
            'alias' => 'Date', 
            'type' => 'INNER', 
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array(
                'Date.schedule_id = Schedule.id',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'conditions'=>array(
        'Date.start >=' => $start_date,
        'Date.start <=' => $end_date,
    ),
    'order'=>'Event.created DESC',
    'limit'=>5
));
```

It's a bit chunky, but results in the exact query I want.

**UPDATE**

Let's break your code in parts and see where we could improve it. The first part is the preparation for the `find`. I've rewritten your code trying to make it shorter, and this is what I came up with:

```
// Default options go here
$defaultOpts = array(
    'start' => date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00',
    'end' => date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59',
    'limit' => 10
)

// Use default options if nothing is passed, otherwise merge passed options with defaults
$opts = is_array($opts) ? array_merge($defaultOpts, $opts) : $defaultOpts;

// Initialize array to hold query conditions
$conditions = array();

//date conditions
$conditions[] = array(
    "Date.start >=" => $qOpts['start'],
    "Date.start <=" => $qOpts['end'],
));

//cities conditions
if(isset($opts['cities']) && is_array($opts['cities'])) {
    $conditions['OR'] = array();
    $conditions['OR'][] = array('Venue.city_id'=>$opts['cities']);
    $conditions['OR'][] = array('Restaurant.city_id'=>$opts['cities']);
}

//event types conditions
//$opts['event_types'] = array('1');
if(isset($opts['event_types']) && is_array($opts['event_types'])) {
    $conditions[] = 'EventTypesEvents.event_type_id' => $opts['event_types']
}

//event sub types conditions
if(isset($opts['event_sub_types']) && is_array($opts['event_sub_types'])) {
    $conditions[] = 'EventSubTypesEvents.event_sub_type_id' => $opts['event_sub_types']
}

//event sub sub types conditions
if(isset($opts['event_sub_types']) && is_array($opts['event_sub_sub_types'])) {
    $conditions[] = 'EventSubSubTypesEvents.event_sub_sub_type_id' => $opts['event_sub_sub_types']
}
```

Notice that I eliminated most of the ORs. That's because you can pass an array as a value in `conditions`, and Cake will make it an `IN(...)` statement in the SQL Query. For example:  `'Model.field' => array(1,2,3)` generates `'Model.field IN (1,2,3)'`. This works just like ORs, but requires less code. So the code block above does exactly the same your code was doing, but it's shorter.

Now comes the complex part, the `find` itself.

Usually I'd recommend the forced joins alone, without Containable, and with `'recursive'=>false`. I believe this *usually* is the best way to deal with complex finds. With Associations and Containable, Cake runs several SQL queries against the database (one query per Model/table), which tends to be inefficient. Also, Containable not always returns the expected results (as you noticed when you tried it).

**But** since in your case there are *four* complex associations involved, maybe a mixed approach will be the ideal solution - otherwise, it would be too complicated to clean-up the duplicate data. (The 4 complex associations are: Event hasMany Dates [through Event hasMany Schedule, Schedule hasMany Date], Event HABTM EventType, Event HABTM EventSubType, Event HABTM EventSubSubType). So, we could let Cake handle data retrieval of EventType, EventSubType and EventSubSubType, avoiding too many duplicates.

So here is what I suggest: use joins for all the required filtering, but do not include Date and [Sub[Sub]]Types in fields. Because of the model associations you have, Cake will automatically run extra queries against the DB to fetch those bits of data. No Containable needed.

The code:

```
// We already fetch the data from these 2 models through
// joins + fields, so we can unbind them for the next find,
// avoiding extra unnecessary queries. 
$this->unbindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('Restaurant', 'Venue'));

$data = $this->find('all', array(
    // The other fields required will be added by Cake later
    'fields' => "
        Event.*, 
        Restaurant.id, Restaurant.name, Restaurant.slug, Restaurant.address, Restaurant.GPS_Lon, Restaurant.GPS_Lat, Restaurant.city_id,
        Venue.id, Venue.name, Venue.slug, Venue.address, Venue.GPS_Lon, Venue.GPS_Lat, Venue.city_id,
        City.id, City.name, City.url_name
    ",  
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => $this->Schedule->table,
            'alias' => 'Schedule',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => 'Schedule.event_id = Event.id',
        ),
        array(
            'table' => $this->Schedule->Date->table,
            'alias' => 'Date',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => 'Date.schedule_id = Schedule.id',
        ),
        array(
            'table' => $this->EventTypesEvent->table,
            'alias' => 'EventTypesEvents',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => 'EventTypesEvents.event_id = Event.id',
        ),
        array(
            'table' => $this->EventSubSubTypesEvent->table,
            'alias' => 'EventSubSubTypesEvents',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => 'EventSubSubTypesEvents.event_id = Event.id',
        ),
        array(
            'table' => $this->Restaurant->table,
            'alias' => 'Restaurant',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => 'Event.restaurant_id = Restaurant.id',
        ),
        array(
            'table' => $this->City->table,
            'alias' => 'RestaurantCity',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => 'Restaurant.city_id = city.id',
        ),
        array(
            'table' => $this->Venue->table,
            'alias' => 'Venue',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => 'Event.venue_id = Venue.id',
        ),
        array(
            'table' => $this->City->table,
            'alias' => 'VenueCity',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => 'Venue.city_id = city.id',
        ),
    ),
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'limit' => $opts['limit'],
    'recursive' => 2
));
```

We eliminated `contains`, and some of the extra queries Cake was running because of it. Most joins are of type `INNER`. This means that at least one record must exist on both tables involved in the join, or you'll get less results then you'd expect. I'm assuming each Event takes place at a Restaurant **OR** a Venue, but not both, that's why I used `LEFT` for those tables (and cities). If some of the fields used in the joins are optional, you should use `LEFT` instead of `INNER` on the related joins.

If we used `'recursive'=>false` here, we'd still get the right events, and no data repetition, but dates and [Sub[Sub]]Types would be missing. With the 2 levels of recursion, Cake will automatically loop through the returned events, and for each event it will run the necessary queries to fetch the associated model data.

This is almost what you were doing, but without Containable, and with a few extra tweaks. I know it's still a long, ugly and boring piece of code, but after all there are 13 database tables involved...

This is all untested code, but I believe it should work.

Comment: I understand the reason for the foreign key=>false on dates, but is it necessary for Schedule, since they're related?  Thank, i'll try this out!

Comment: @Dave, **bfavaretto** is setting `foreignKey => false` so he can explicitly code the JOIN `condition`. This is helpful when you don't have a straightforward JOIN or one that follows CakePHP conventions. However, in your case, you may be able to use `foreignKey` appropriately.

Comment: @Dave, I remembered something: the query above will return all fields from all those 3 models. If you don't need them all, you should add the 'fields' option to `$this->Event->find` (an array containing the fields you need).

Comment: @bfavaretto - thanks.  Getting too many fields would be a great problem to have.  I've implemented it - testing now.

Comment: @bfavaretto - it's only returning a single date record.  In one of the ones I tried, it returned 3 different schedules for the event, each of which have date(s), but it only returned a single Date record.

Comment: Correction - it's returning multiple dates, but it's returning all fields/tables then a single date row, then a duplicate of all fields/tables, then another date row...etc etc.  I tried grouping by Event.id, but - then I only get 1 Date row total.  Also - I had to use $this->Schedule->Date->table since Event doesn't have a direct relationship to Date (was that the right thing to do?)

Comment: And last weird thing - it won't return ANY 'Date' rows unless I specify that I want the Date fields via a 'fields'=>array   ...everything else seems to return by default, but - not Dates.

Comment: I ended up having to use a combination of joins and containable.  If you know a way to do it via just joins, I'd be happy to hear, but I couldn't manage.

Comment: @Dave - since `Event hasMany Schedule` and `Schedule hasMany Date`, it's normal for the database to return repeated data in the results. When you say that joins+containable worked, do you mean the repetitions do not appear anymore, and Events, Schedules and Dates are properly nested? If so, it's probably Cake doing its magic after running the query. Can you put the SQL Query and the results in a pastebin? With that info I tell you what is going on, and if there is another solution.

Comment: Besides the long update I just added, I must say your [Sub[Sub]]Types seem a bit odd to me -- specifically, the fact that you have 3 separate tables/models for this, instead of a single table storing a tree. Consider these type/subtype examples: Sports [type] > Football game [subtype], and Movie Screening [type] > Action Movie [subtype]. What prevents users to assign Type:Sports, Subtype:Action Movie to the same Event?

Comment: I'm trying your update now - thanks very much.  As far as the [Sub[Sub]]Types, it's the only way I could think to do it.  What's keeping them from adding a non-related subtype, is - I'm storing the 'type_id' in the subtypes table, then only displaying subtypes under it's corresponding parent type when they first select the type.  That being said, I'd love a link or explanation on the better way to do this.  Thanks again - I'll let you know if I get the events find working.

Comment: I've been working on trying to implement this for the past hour and a half, but - there are a lot of issues.  It's returning WAY more fields than specified in the fields list, it can't find a lot of the fields it's trying to join on, and more...  Haven't given up, but am losing hope.

Comment: @Dave - don't loose hope! You made it work using joins+containable, in the worst case you stick with that. The only problem with that approach is that is not the most efficient one, and may be slow depending on the size of your database. Concerning the  [Sub[Sub]]Types, okay, you do have a mechanism to avoid inconsistencies, that's good. The tree I suggested is just another way of doing it, forget about it (you already have enough trouble!).

Comment: As for the extra fields: if they (A) belong to the Event model, replace `Event.*` from the fields list with the actual fields you want; if (B) they come from Type, Subtype, Subsubtype, Date or Schedule, then I believe Containable will be the only way to clean it up; (C) if they come from other models, you'll have to unbind them before the find (note that you may have to unbind from other models beside Event).

Comment: I'll keep trying.  The extra fields were coming FROM the unbinded models - Example: I got every single Restaurant field in the table.

Comment: Replace my original unbind with this: `$this->unbindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('Restaurant', 'Venue'), false);`

Comment: Added another answer, discussing your problem in a more generic way.

Comment: I really appreciate your help / attempt, but after reading both answers 20 times over (each), I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: It's still returning duplicate events, and it's not returning more than one Date

Comment: Ok - so I group => Event.id, which limits the duplicates, and the "not returning more than one Date" is likely due to specifying the Join instead of allowing the recursive 2 to get the Dates - reason being, I can't even pull 1 record with recursive 2 without getting an "Allowed memory size..." error.  any thoughts?  I've given you the bounty (tyvm for help), but am refraining from marking as answer till I know it works.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! About the memory issue: you could try allowing PHP to use more memory. E.g.: `ini_set('memory_limit','32M');`, or directly on php.ini). That said, I realized I'm overcomplicating things for the sake of performance. Try the following: (A) remove the unbinds; (B) make `fields` = `DISTINCT Event.*` (just that, nothing from other models); (C) Remove the grouping, you don't need it (the dupes are caused by multiple matching Restaurants, Venues, Cities).

Comment: Is there some way you can share your complete code and database? This discussion has gone too far here (the system is even suggesting we move to chat), and I'm sure I can fix the problem if I can reproduce your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could *try* the following, assuming Cake 1.3 and using containable behaviour. I assumed that the date fields in your table are called `start_date` and `end_date`, so these conditions might need adjusting.

This may, or may not work, and will likely produce a massive query if you have a lot of data, so some further refinement is probably necessary - certainly with the fields selected.

You could post the query generated, if it runs, and we may be able to help adjust it further.

```
/* in your EventController (the method) for on the fly */
$this->Event->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

/* Your dates */
$x_date = '2011-06-01';
$y_date = '2011-07-01';

$this->paginate = array(
            'limit'=>10,
            'order'=>'Event.created DESC',
            'contain'=>array(
                'Schedule',
                'Event'=>array(
                    'conditions'=>array('Event.start_date'=>$x_date,
                                        'Event.end_date'<=$y_date)
                )
            ),
        );

$this->set('events',$this->Paginate('Event'));

// print_r($events);
```

Comment: This sounds great, but you didn't mention the Dates table at all - it's the one that has the actual dates to check against.  Thoughts?

Comment: updated my question w/ what I tried based on your answer... still no luck :(

Comment: The conditions in that code sample are not valid. They are not arrays. It should be: `array('Event.start_date >=' => $x_date, 'Event.end_date <=' => $y_date)`... CakepPHP will parse out the operation which should be _in_ the key (string) and the `=>` is an array key/value association operator.

Comment: @Andrew - good catch - but now I'm having the problem that it's pulling the events regardless of the date in the conditions.. thoughts?  The condition is right now - it's just only showing the Date date if it's date is in the right range - but will pull the event's data regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Dave, you have a reasonably complicated problem to solve, which requires more than basic Cake. You must understand what's going on in order to be able to solve it. I'm assuming you don't have much experience with SQL, and don't know much 'under-the-hood' Cake. So I'll try to explain the basics here.

Consider you have two tables, called 'main' and 'related':

```
main             related

id | val         id | main_id | val
1  | A           1  | 1       | Foo
2  | B           2  | 1       | FooBar
3  | C           3  | 2       | Bar
4  | D           4  | 3       | BarFoo
```

In Cake, you'll have models Main and Related to deal with them. `Main hasMany Related`, and  `Related belongsTo Main`. Now you do the following (from a method inside Main):

```
$data = $this->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 1
));
```

Here is what Cake will do behind the scenes:

1. Retrieve all rows from table 'main'

   ```
   SELECT * FROM main
   ```
2. With the results, Cake will build an array of IDs, which will then be used to get the data for the associated model Related. This data will be fetched from MySQL using a query like this:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM related WHERE main_id IN ([comma_separated_list_of_ids_here])
   ```
3. Finally, Cake will loop through results array from Main, and add the related data to each row as applicable. When it finishes, it returns the "decorated" array.

Sometimes, depending on the type of association, Cake will do an extra SQL query for every row retrieved for the main model. That can be really slow. The solution would be to use single query to get data from both tables, and that's what JOINs are for. The problem with that is data repetition. For example:

```
SELECT Main.*, Related.*
FROM main as Main
INNER JOIN related AS Related
ON Related.main_id = main.id
```

Results:

```
    Main.id | Main.val | Related.id | Related.main_id | Related.val
    1       | A        | 1          | 1               | Foo
    1       | A        | 2          | 1               | FooBar
    2       | B        | 3          | 2               | Bar
    3       | C        | 4          | 3               | BarFoo
```

Things to notice here:

1. We have 2 rows for Main.id = 1. The difference between them is at Related.id and Related.val. If you remove those columns from the SELECT clause, the repetition will go away. This is very useful if you need to add conditions on the related table. For example:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT Main.*
   FROM main as Main
   INNER JOIN related AS Related
   ON Related.main_id = main.id
   WHERE Related.val LIKE '%Foo%'
   ```

   Gives:

```
   
        Main.id | Main.val
        1       | A       
        3       | C
```

There are actually 2 rows on related that match on our conditions (Foo and FooBar), but A shows up only once in the results beacause we didn't ask SQL to display Related.val, and also told it to ignore exact duplicates (with `DISTINCT`).

2. On the original results, there item D from Main is missing! That's because we used an `INNER JOIN`, which limits the results to rows from Main that also have one or more corresponding rows on Related. If we used a `LEFT JOIN`, the results would have an extra line, as below:

```
    Main.id | Main.val | Related.id | Related.main_id | Related.val
    1       | A        | 1          | 1               | Foo
    1       | A        | 2          | 1               | FooBar
    2       | B        | 3          | 2               | Bar
    3       | C        | 4          | 3               | BarFoo
    4       | D        | NULL       | NULL            | NULL
```

(if you need more details on INNER vs. LEFT JOINs, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-full-join-in-mysq)). (**EDIT**: link updated)

Back to the duplicates: it's easy to clean them up with a simple `foreach` loop in PHP. It's simple when there are just 2 tables involved, but becomes more and more complex for every extra table you add to the query (if the new table has a one-to-many relationship with either main or related).

But you do have lots of tables and associations involved. So, the solution I suggested above is somewhat a compromise between performance and code simplicity. Let me try to explain my line of thought when I wrote it.

- You need to deal with 13 tables to get all the data you want. You need to display data that comes from most of those tables, and need to filter events based on quite a few tables too.
- Cake alone can't understand what you want, and will return too much data, including stuff you expected it to have filtered out.
- There are some 1-n and n-n relashionships involved. If you jast add all 13 to a single query with JOINs, the result will have too many dupes, and will be unmanageable.
- So I decided to try a mixed approach: start by getting a filtered list of events, with no dupes, then let Cake 'decorate' it with data from *some* associated models. To do that, you must:

  1. `JOIN` all tables which need conditions applied to them. This will allow us to retrieve our final list of events, considering all conditions, with a single query.
  2. If any of the tables you `JOIN`ed can cause duplicates, do not include their fields in the `SELECT` clause (or Cake's `fields` list). If the associations are properly setup, Cake will run an extra query later to get the associated data (since we used `recursive=2`).
  3. Prevent Cake from running extra queries to get data we already retrieved on our main query. This is done by unbinding the proper models before running the find.

  If this is still returning fields you don't want, and such fields come from associated models, you must use Containable to tell Cake which fields you want from each of those models.

I know it might sound complicated, but you won't be able to solve this on your own unless you understand what Cake does, and how SQL works. I hope this helps.