# Trying to get "City" data from Event->Venue->City using 'contain' in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-1.3, containable

I'm trying to return a list of `events`, and include the `city` where it's taking place.  The city is only associated through the Event's `Venue` though.

Below is the code I'm using.  It returns all the correct data, but it doesn't return ANY city data (other than the city_id field in Venue - which I'm not sure why it's returning).

Associations:

```
Event belongsTo Venue
Venue hasMany Event

Venue belongsTo City    
City hasMany Venue
```

Code:

```
        $this->Event->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        $events = $this->Event->find('all', array(
            'limit' => 5,
            'order' => 'Event.created DESC',
            'fields' => array(
                'name',
                'description',
                'phone',
                'price_general',
                'price_child',
                'price_adult',
                'price_child',
                'tickets_url'
            ),
            'contain' => array(
                'Venue' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'name',
                        'address',
                        'city_id',
                    ),
                    'City' => array(
                        'fields' => array(
                            'City.name',
                            'state'
                        ),
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'City.id' => 'Venue.city_id'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'Schedule' => array(
                    'fields'=>array(),
                    'Date' => array(
                        'conditions'=>array(
                            'Date.start >=' => $start_date,
                            'Date.start <=' => $end_date,
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
        ));
```

Bonus answer:  (that I have currently asked in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373203/select-all-events-with-event-schedule-date-between-start-and-end-dates-in-cakep)) - The Date conditions are supposed to filter which events show up, but instead, they're only filtering which Date data to show.

---

**WORKING ANSWER: (thanks bancer)**

```
    $this->Event->recursive = -1;
    $options['joins'] = array(
            array('table' => 'schedules',
                'alias' => 'Schedule',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Event.id = Schedule.event_id',
                )
            ),
            array('table' => 'dates',
                'alias' => 'Date',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Date.schedule_id = Schedule.id',
                )
            )
        );
        $options['fields'] = array(
            'Event.name',
            'Schedule.start_date',
            'Date.start',
        );
        $options['limit'] = 5;
        $events = $this->Event->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: It would help if you provide the query that is produced by your code.

Comment: What is the actual query produced by your code? It seems that you have an error in the Date 'conditions'. It should be `'Date.schedule_id' => 'Schedule.id'`. Comment out 'fields' and 'limit' arrays temporary until you ensure that you can retrieve all columns and rows.

Comment: Also take a look at this manual to better understand difference between left and right joins http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @bancer - so - if I understand it right (been awhile for me to do joins), I should always be using Left Join when Event is my main query, right?

Comment: I think in most cases you will need left joins if I understand your schema correctly.

Comment: Right - but that's not working per code above.

Comment: What is not working? What query does it produce?

Comment: @bancer - The problem so far is - if I put "LEFT" as the date join, it doesn't show the Date data.  If I put RIGHT, then it does, but doesn't show the Event or Schedule data.

Comment: What is the query that the code in your question generates?

Comment: NOW we're getting somewhere - SQL posted.  When I change 'Date.id' to `Date`.`id` manually (navicat), it returns all the data.  Now, how do I get Cake to do it?

Comment: I am going to repeat myself but it seems you have an error in Date 'conditions'. It should be `'Date.schedule_id' => 'Schedule.id'`. Actually, better would be `'Schedule.id' => 'Date.schedule_id'`

Comment: AHA!!! (First off, sorry for missing your previous comment).  You were right - ALSO - I needed to change ' => ' to just = within quotes (like the one above it.  Working now!!!  Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to avoid using Containable. It generates too many queries in some cases. A better way for complex queries is [to join tables "manually"](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables).

Another option I would consider at the first place is to search through 'Venue' model without using Containable like this: `$this->Event->Venues->find('all', ...)`. As Venues directly associated with Cities and Events there should be possible to get what you want without extra complexities.

**Update:** take a look at the question [How to change the sequence of 'joins' in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470182/how-to-change-the-sequence-of-joins-in-cakephp)

Comment: I'd like to get this way functioning before I try to go down another endless road of not understanding.  I understand what you mean, and will look into doing it "manually" later, but - for now, I just want to get it working, slow or otherwise.

Comment: Also - I need to get more things than Events, Venues, and Cities - like Schedules, which is only linked via Events

Comment: So I think I give up - how do I do this manual join?  I've read the link you provided "join tables manually", but I've tried it, and it doesn't work (or I'm doing something wrong).  Don't suppose you can point me in the right direction on how to translate their code to this example?

Comment: Code I wrote that worked (based on this answer) is listed above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

instead of containable, did you try including the city data in fields itself by fields=> array('','','City.name)

Comment: Since an Event is not associated directly with a City, the only place I can think to add it (other than the place it already is) is under Venue - and that returns: SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'City.name